# XMPP photo type is not given in response when requested

Tags: xmpp, photo, vcf-vcard

We are trying to implement facebook chat from our own ejabberd server using transports.But when we requested for photo of the contact, it gives binval but not type of photo.Can any one help me out in resolving this issue.

---

***EDIT***

In response to the follow-up questions, this is the request I send to the server:

```
var imgcard = $iq({ to:name, from:connection.jid, type: 'get', id :'avatar'+name})
    .c('vCard', {xmlns:'vcard-temp' })
connection.sendIQ(imgcard, getImg);
```

The response is:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client"
        to="yummy61@li188-236.members.linode.com/24581935361290171300602628"
        from="666346810@facebook.li188-236.members.linode.com" 
        id="avatar666346810@facebook.li188-236.members.linode.com"
        type="result">
        <vcard xmlns="vcard-temp">
            <desc></desc>
            <photo>
                <binval>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/9sAQwACAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAgIEAwICAgIFBAQDBAY... 
                </binval>
            </photo>
        </vcard>
    </iq>
</body>
```

I get the binval but not image type. Can any one tell the mistake I made?

Answer (score 1):

Using [JAXL library](http://jaxl.net) to retrieve vCard for connected account, I get following response back which does have `<TYPE>image/jpeg</TYPE>` node attached to it.

```
[16000] 2010-11-09 23:49:47 - [[XMPPSend]] body
<body rid="5674" sid="41bbdfe522c4e1c3a3e1a4cfe20968f1" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind"><iq type="get" id="7" from="abhinavsingh@chat.facebook.com/jaxl.1289375373_ba14f160_494AE079BF19C"><vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"/></iq></body>

[16000] 2010-11-09 23:49:48 - [[XMPPGet]]
<body sid="41bbdfe522c4e1c3a3e1a4cfe20968f1" rid="5674" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind"><iq from="abhinavsingh@chat.facebook.com" to="abhinavsingh@chat.facebook.com/jaxl.1289375373_ba14f160_494AE079BF19C" id="7" type="result"><vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"><FN>Abhinav Singh</FN><PHOTO><TYPE>image/jpeg</TYPE><BINVAL></BINVAL></PHOTO></vCard></iq></body>
```

What exactly do you get back in response from facebook chat servers?

Comment: XEP-0153 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) Section 5 (Implementation Notes) says: "The XML character data of the <TYPE/> element is a hint. If the XML character data of the <TYPE/> specifies a content type that does not match the data provided in the <BINVAL/> element, the processing application MUST adhere to the content type of the actual image data and MUST ignore the <TYPE/>. If the <TYPE/> is something other than image/gif, image/jpeg, or image/png, it SHOULD be ignored."